# I want to extract a sample from a .wav audio file, how can I do that?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, sample, sample-rate

first of all i apologize because i am new to programming. now I have .wav files as in section A in the picture. My goal is to output partition B from partition A. I do not want a direct solution from you, but what are the issues that I need to research? How can I find the right path? How can you help me ?[image]

Some of the people around me said that I should learn the math of the job They said that I should learn Dsp

Comment: What do you mean "by decibel"? Do you want to relate the values to actual real world sound volume or pressure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.